# How to use a Set in Swift 3.0 without generic usage

Tags: swift, swift3

First of all i have to say i come from Java programming and compared with Java everything in Swift 3.0 seems to be totally complicated. I thought what i want to do is easy but it turned out it is not.

I have two objects:

```
protocol Customer {
}
```

and:

```
class Consulter {
}
```

I want my `Consulter` class to hold a `Set` of `Customer`:

```
class Consulter {
    var customers: Set<Customer>;
}
```

Ok here the first thing. The Compiler now is complaining that `Customer` has to implement `Hashable`... really? Swift isnt doing that for me? Ok. So lets go for it:

```
func ==(lhs: Customer, rhs: Customer) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue;
}

protocol Customer: Hashable {

    var: hashValue: Int {
        return "123".hashValue;
    }
}
```

And in my `Consulter` class i now would have to do the following:

```
class Consulter<T: Customer> {

    var customers: Set<T>;
}
```

Ok this is working. But now i have another class:

```
func ==(lhs: Location, rhs: Location) -> Bool { // here the error!
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue;
}

class Location<T: Customer> : Hashable {

    var customer: T;

    ....
}
```

For the `Equatable` of the class `Location` i now get the error:

```
Reference to generic type 'Location' requires arguments in <...>
```

So what argument is the compiler expecting here? I dont know any concrete types at this point.

**EDIT**

my `Customer` protocol will later have different concrete implementations. A `Customer` can for example be a `Family` or a `Person`. In the `Consulter` class i want to have a `Set` of `Customer` containing both: families and persons. I think this is a simple and logical approach.

Comment: `Customer` is a protocol (possibly for customer related _types_ to conform to), and possibly not something you want to use a as a concrete type. You could simply include a constraint that the conformance to the `Customer` protocol implies conformance to `Hashable` (`protocol Customer: Hashable {}`). This way you move the responsibility to conformance to `Hashable` to the actual types that you consider to be `Customer`'s.

Comment: i did not understand a single word of what you just wrote. so i explain my thoughts further in an edit.

Comment: Since you intend to use types conforming to `Customer` in applications where they must be `Hashable` (e.g. as members of a `Set`), there is no reason why not to add this `Hashable` constraint directly to the `Customer` protocol (`protocol Customer: Hashable {}`). W.r.t. your error, since `Location` is a generic type, you must specify the type of the generic `T` in order to work with a concrete type (e.g. the concrete type `Location<SomeTypeConformingToCustomer>`).

Comment: but the type in `Location` can be `Family` or `Person` which are both implementations of `Customer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you intend to use types conforming to `Customer` in applications where they must be `Hashable` (e.g. as members of a `Set`), there is no reason why not to add this `Hashable` constraint directly to the `Customer` protocol. This way you move the responsibility to conformance to `Hashable` to the actual types that you consider to be `Customer`'s

```
protocol Customer: Hashable {}

class Consulter<T: Customer> {
    var customers: Set<T>?
}

class Location<T: Customer>: Hashable {
    var customer: T
    init(customer: T) { self.customer = customer }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return customer.hashValue
    }
}

func ==<T: Customer>(lhs: Location<T>, rhs: Location<T>) -> Bool { 
    return lhs.customer == rhs.customer /* && ... test other properties */ 
}
```

Also, be careful using `X.hashValue == Y.hashValue` for testing for equality, since there is no guarantee that hashvalues are unique (consider them mainly used for clever "bin" categorization).

Or, since Swift 3

```
// ... as above

class Location<T: Customer>: Hashable {
    var customer: T
    init(customer: T) { self.customer = customer }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return customer.hashValue
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Location<T>, rhs: Location<T>) -> Bool { 
        return lhs.customer == rhs.customer /* && ... test other properties */ 
    }
}
```

Comment: that is exactly what i needed to know. I have it already like that. all i needed was to move the `func ==(lhs: Location<T>....` inside my class and to make it static. Thank you.